# How can I pass prop to value of input with vue.js 2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

My vue component is like this :

```
<template>
    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
         <form method="post" :action="baseUrl+'/product/edit'">
            ...
            <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{productId}}">
            ...
         </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props:['productId'],
        ...
    }
</script>
```

There exist error like this :

> value="{{productId}}": Interpolation inside attributes has been removed.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [binding syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes).

```
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" v-bind:value="productId">
```

Or

```
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" :value="productId">
```